# Excel vba: program performance is slow, out of memory error when dealing with large dataset in collection

Tags: vba, performance, excel, memory

So I have a really huge excel spreadsheet with about 100 thousands rows. Each row represents a client. Each column stores that client's name, debt, probability of default and so on. There are about 12 columns.

In my code, I loop through the rows and store the data for each client as a class object, then add that object to a collection:

```
Function getClients(dataWorkbook As Workbook)
    Dim resultColl As Collection
    Set resultColl = New Collection

    ...
     With dataWorkbook.Worksheets(globals("DATA_SHEET"))
        For i = firstRow To lastRow
            Set clientCopy = New Client
            clientCopy.setClientName = .Cells(i, column_names).value
            clientCopy.setContractNumber = .Cells(i, column_contract_numbers).value
            ...

resultColl.Add clientCopy
        Next
    End With

    Set getClients = resultColl
End Function
```

Then for each client in the collection I calculate the random numbers and store them in a collection for that client (the collection of size N, depending the number a user wants, usually 1000 - 5000).

Then I go through those random numbers of each client and store an outcome in an outcomes collection, depending on the random number's value (if the number is greater than the client's number P, then I store 0, else 1).

Then I calculate a financial result for each client, meaning, I check for each outcome in the outcomes collection and store appropriate values in losses and profits collections, depending if the outcome is 1 or 0.

These methods inside the `Client` class:

```
Public Sub generateRandoms()
    Set randomNumbers = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To simulationCount
        randomNumbers.Add Rnd()
        'Debug.Print "random: " & randomNumbers(i)
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub calculateOutcomes()
    Set outcomes = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    If totalPd <> -1 Then
        For i = 1 To simulationCount
            If randomNumbers(i) < totalPd Then
                outcomes.Add 1
            Else
                outcomes.Add 0
            End If
        Next
    Else
        For i = 1 To simulationCount
            outcomes.Add Null
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub calculateFinancialResult()
    Set losses = New Collection
    Set profits = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To outcomes.Count
        If outcomes(i) = 1 Then
            losses.Add totalLoss
            profits.Add 0
        ElseIf outcomes(i) = 0 Then
            losses.Add 0
            profits.Add totalProfit
        Else
            losses.Add Null
            profits.Add Null
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The code in the main module goes like this:

```
Dim clientsColl As Collection
Set clientsColl = getClients(dataWorkbook)

Dim clientCopy As Client
For Each clientCopy In clientsColl
    clientCopy.setSimulationCount = globals("SIMULATION_COUNT")
    clientCopy.generateRandoms 'up to this line it's fast
    'clientCopy.calculateOutcomes 'this line is slow, so i have to shut excel down
    'clientCopy.calculateFinancialResult

    clientCopy.clearSums
Next

MsgBox ("Done for")
```

While the data collection from the data workbook is rather slow, it takes a reasonable enough amount of time. At the same time, the calculations itself are extraordinary slow. I tried to figure out which function or sub takes the most time. So far it looks like `calculateOutcomes` is pretty slow, while `generateRandoms` is quite fast and takes less than a minute.

I don't understand why is that so - both of them loop through each client and store data in a collection N times. At the same time the first is fast, while the second is slow. If I don't terminate the excel eventually I encounter an `Out of memory` error. Why?

Is there anything I can do about this code's performance? Any suggestions are appreciated. What are the general practices in situations like this?

Comment: You could treat one client at a time. And unless you need to save or display the random values at some point, ditch the intermediate steps and their collections, and just loop once e.g. in calculateFinancialResults.

Comment: If the code works, consider posting this to [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Excelosaurus I do need to display the random values, as well as the outcomes, unfortunatelly...